# Transferring git repository using REST API fails

Tags: git, github, github-api, octokit, octokit-js

I'm trying to achieve Github repo transfer (on both private and public repos) via their REST API. For this I have tried the below options

1. With Github App and Oktokit

   const app = new App({
   appId: <App_Id>,
   privateKey: <Private_Key>,
   });

   const octokit = await app.getInstallationOctokit(<Installation_Id>);

   let data = await octokit.request("POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/transfer", {
   owner,
   new_owner,
   new_name
   })

Error: ***"Resource not accessible by integration"***

2. Github PAT token and Octokit

   const octokit = new Octokit({auth: "<PAT_Token>"});

   const response = await octokit.rest.repos.transfer({
   owner,
   repo,
   new_owner
   });

Error: ***"Resource not accessible by personal access token"***

3. Tried with Plain curl URL as well; however no luck, similar error response.

[image: For Github App]

[image: For Github PAT]

I have given all permission for this test drive. no luck!

Am I missing anything here? I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: git repo transfer api: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#transfer-a-repository

Comment: this might very well be an API problem. I'd try https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/api-and-webhooks as some Hubbers are watching over there.

Did you try to with another another repository / org?

Comment: yes I tried with different repos; even tried after changing their visibility as well. still same issue.

Comment: Github community discussion ref: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/60014

Comment: The repo transfer is working with classic PAT token; not with fine-grained tokens.

Comment: Can you clarify your question about classic vs fine-grained PAT. At least to me, that is an important distinction. The classic PAT is an OAuth token, the fine-graned PAT works similarly to how GitHub Apps and GitHub Actions authenticate.